# VIM - shell working directory integration

Tags: shell, vim

I use cscope integrated to VIM to navidate a large code base. I can use the :E command to navigate the directory structure. But, how do I open a shell on a specific directory where I navigated to?

I came across `:cd %:p:h`
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: got the answer to this. `set autochdir`

Comment: @kev `:shell` and `:!` opens the dir from which we started. It doesnot move along with navigation inside vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Vim, there are always multiple ways to suit your needs.

You could for example create a shortcut (called *mapping*) for the command you've found (and/or combine this with opening a shell):

```
:nnoremap <Leader>. :cd %:p:h<CR>
```

But this particular use case is so prevalent that there's actually an option for it:

```
:set autochdir
```

As an alternative, some people always open Vim from the root directory of their current project; this ensures short (and consistent!) paths, too. There are even plugins that automatically `:cd` to the project dir for you.

Answer (score 1):

The `set autochdir` maybe effect some plugins, so you can use this to auto-change directory.

```
autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
```

Enjoy it.

### Reference

- [Set working directory to the current file - Vim Tips Wiki - Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file)
- [Add vimshell.vim plugin · Issue #22 · chusiang/vimrc](https://github.com/chusiang/vimrc/issues/22)

Answer (score 0):

from a book:

`cnoremap <expr> %% getcmdtype() == ':' ? expand('%:h').'/' : '%%'`

usage:

in command mode, type %% and it will expand to the current path. This is works with any command that takes a path